# Thread for each item in list, running two functions for each item in list

Tags: python, multithreading

I'll preface this with I'm new to threading. I have tried a couple different ways, and come sort of close to success, but not really.

I have a list that is created from a file as such:

```
with open(server_file, 'rU') as fi:
    servers = fi.read().split('\n')
```

I have two functions grabdata() and runcheck() that I need to be run for each item in the list, each pair (grabdata and then runcheck) in their own thread.

The functions:

```
def grabdata():
    for server in servers:
        print "Checking: "+str(server)
        devnull = open(os.devnull, 'wb') # hide unnecessary output
        command = "wget -O tmp/servers/" +server + " " + server+"/avicapture.html#status"
        result = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=devnull).communicate()[0]

def runcheck():
    for server in servers:
        file_path = current_dir+"/tmp/servers/"+server
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            file_content = file.readlines()
            for x in file_content:
                match = re.search( r'In Progress \((.*)%\)', x)
                if match:
                    temp = match.group(1)
                    results = temp
                    if int(temp) >= 90 :
                        message = "\nServer: "+server+ "... {0}% 
                    print(message)
```

How would I properly do this?

Comment: With your current setup, you don't.  You need to refactor so that you have methods for `grabdata(server)` and `runcheck(server)`.  Once you can call each method separately for a single server you'll have significantly better luck trying to start threads for each server.

Comment: @g.d.d.c
Good point. I've done that now, so each function takes one argument, and I call it with:

for server in servers: call each func with arg as 'server'

Comment: Ok.  Next, write a function for `grab_and_check(server)`, then you can start threads with `Thread(target=grab_and_check, args=(server,))`.

Comment: @d.g.g.c Just wanted to say thanks. This helped me make the script more modular. In the end, I ended up going with multiprocessing in a pool though.

Comment: No problem.  You'd have needed to modularize to make effective use of multiprocessing anyway, so I'm glad you found a viable approach.